# slider in jquery that shows 4 slides concurrently

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want a slider, that shows 4 list items concurrently and with click on the next/previous button the next/previous slide slides-in and the slide on the other end drops out of the qeue so that everytime 4 images are shown.

My HTML:

```
<div id="slider">
  <a href="#" class="control_next">>></a>
  <a href="#" class="control_prev"><</a>
  <ul>
    <li>SLIDE 1</li>
    <li style="background: #aaa;">SLIDE 2</li>
    <li>SLIDE 3</li>
    <li style="background: #aaa;">SLIDE 4</li>
    <li>SLIDE 5</li>
    <li style="background: #aaa;">SLIDE 6</li>
    <li>SLIDE 7</li>
    <li style="background: #aaa;">SLIDE 8</li>
  </ul>  
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mCze7/115/

The current working example shows only one slide and with click on next/prev button the new slide overlaps the old one completely.

How can i manage to show 4 items concurrently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change just the linecode that defines the size of the mask container:

```
$('#slider').css({ width: slideWidth, height: slideHeight });
```

On the `width` value multiply by 4 or the `n` number of slides you want to show:

```
$('#slider').css({ width: slideWidth*4, height: slideHeight });
```

[**Updated Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mCze7/117/)

Comment: Gald to help U @StandardNerd